# Single pass algorithm for finding the topX percent of items

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for a single-pass algorithm for finding the topX percent of floats in a stream where I do not know the total number ahead of time ... but its on the order of 5-30 million floats. It needs to be single-pass since the data is generated on the fly and recreate the exact stream a second time.

The algorithm I have so far is to keep a sorted list of the topX items that I've seen so far. As the stream continues I enlarge the list as needed. Then I use `bisect_left` to find the insertion point if needed.

Below is the algorithm I have so far:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from random import uniform
from itertools import islice


def data_gen(num):
    for _ in xrange(num):
        yield uniform(0,1)

def get_top_X_percent(iterable, percent = 0.01, min_guess = 1000):

    top_nums = sorted(list(islice(iterable, int(percent*min_guess)))) #get an initial guess

    for ind, val in enumerate(iterable, len(top_nums)):
        if int(percent*ind) > len(top_nums):
            top_nums.insert(0,None)
        newind = bisect_left(top_nums, val)
        if newind > 0:
            top_nums.insert(newind, val)
            top_nums.pop(0)

    return top_nums

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num = 1000000
    all_data = sorted(data_gen(num))
    result = get_top_X_percent(all_data)
    assert result[0] == all_data[-int(num*0.01)], 'Too far off, lowest num:%f' % result[0] 
    print result[0]
```

In the real case the data does not come from any standard distribution (otherwise I could use some statistics knowledge).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

```
top_nums = sorted(list(islice(iterable, int(percent*min_guess)))) #get an initial guess
```

There is no reason to make a list out of it before you sort it.

```
for ind, val in enumerate(iterable, len(top_nums))
```

I dislike abbreviations. I think it makes it harder to figure out what ind and val are doing.

```
   all_data = sorted(data_gen(num))
```

Why are you sorting your test data?

As I understand your problem, your code is wrong. It only works in your test case because you sort the incoming data.

Your algorithm regularly increases the size of the list of values. But when it does so, there have been previous numbers which have been thrown away which may greater then the value you insert at that point. As a result, you cannot be sure you've actually ended up with with the top 1%.

How should you fix it? If you can upper bound the size of your input, then you can start with a list of sufficient size and then scale back at the end. Otherwise I don't think you can do it. The problem being that you cannot throw away any values because there is no way to be sure you won't need them later.

You might consider using a heap. Python has a heapq module including a function heapq.nlargest which does pretty much what you are doing, (but uses a count rather then a percentage) A heap is pretty much a semi-sorted list and lets you do things like find/remove/replace the lowest value without the overhead of actually sorting.

Comment: Actually.  Only a heap can possibly work.  Consider the case where all the incoming data is in strictly descending order.  No value can be discarded because the top *X* percent is always the first arrived items in descending order.  Until the entire stream has been seen, no value can be discarded as the number of slots comprising *X* percent grows.

Comment: @S. Lott, I'm not seeing the connection between "only a heap can possibly work" and the rest of your comment. At the very least, I'd think a sorted list can do the same things a heap can, (with more computational cost)

Comment: True.  A sorted list and lots of other expensive and bad ideas for keeping the data will "work".  Since they'll be more costly, they aren't very good ideas are they?  The heap, however, is a very good idea.  I think it belongs up higher in your answer, because it's a very good ideas.  The theoretical possibility of other less good ideas didn't seem very relevant.

Comment: @S.Lott, you said that only a heap could possibly work. If we are considering what could possibly work the efficiency doesn't matter. A heap is better, although I'm not sure how much. If I recall correctly, I have O(log n) insertion for both a sorted list and a heap. The heap is at the end because I thought it more important to point out that the code doesn't work then how to optimize it.

Comment: Your distinction between bad algorithms which may work eventually and a good algorithm is getting too subtle for me.  I'm sure it's an important hair, but I can't understand splitting it.  The algorithm as presented is fundamentally flawed -- as you noted.  Further, the whole thing can be simplified to just a heap and nothing more.  There's little more to say than you pointed out both flaws.  Feel, free, however, to continue to split whatever hair you need to in your already complete answer.

Comment: @S. Lott, the fundamental flaw in his algoritm isn't solved by using a heap. Just using a heap leaves his algorithm fundamentally flawed. Whether using a heap or sorted list the algorithm will give the wrong answers.

Comment: If the algorithm given is discarded, and a heap is used, then the top *X* percent is available in the heap.  That sounds like what you said.  That's what made sense to me.  Discard the broken algorithm.  Use a heap.  Right?  Isn't that what you said?  That's what my comment meant.  Use a heap.  Just use a heap.  Ignore the broken algorithm.

Comment: @S. Lott, we don't know how big to make the heap. We won't know how big to make the heap until we've seen all the data, but at that point its too late. We need to know from the beginning of the algorithm how many values to keep in the heap, but since we only have a percentage we have a problem.

Comment: @S. Lott, if we solve the problem of how many items to keep, then yes use a heap. But, we've moved from the area of accuracy (What's really really important) to effeciency (which is less important).

Comment: "We won't know how big to make the heap until we've seen all the data".  Precisely.  The only solution is a heap.  "if we solve the problem of how many items to keep"?  What kind of random hypothetical is that?  We can't know that in advance under any circumstances.  Hence the heap as the only sensible solution.

Comment: @S. Lott, wait, are you suggesting putting the entire contents of the incoming data in a heap?

Comment: I can't see how any other approach would work.  Until you've seen `len(stream)` items you don't know how large `X*len(stream)` is, so you don't know how many to "keep".  If the data arrives in strictly descending order, you can't discard anything until you've reached `(1-X)*len(stream)`.  Anyway, that's what appears to be the case to me.

Comment: @S. Lott, ok I misunderstood what you were suggesting. I agree that unless you can determine an upper bound on input size, you are stuck with keeping all values in memory until the end. The confusion resulted because when I suggested a heap, I didn't intend as an entire algorithm merely to replace the sorted list the OP was using for part of his "broken" algorithm. Hence when you started talking about the heap as "the" solution, I was rather confused.

Comment: I also confused because of the emphasis you placed on the heap, which as the data structure seems to be a fairly minor component of the solution. I wasn't really attempting to provide a complete solution because what the OP seems to want (not keeping everything in memory and returning the top 1% doesn't seem to possible.)

Comment: "what the OP seems to want" appears unworkable.  The heap appears workable.  That was my comment.  Only a heap will work.  Other structures that keep all the data may work, but will be inefficient and therefore unworkable.  I'm trying to keep this simple.  The heap is the only thing that's workable.  That was my comment.

Comment: @S. Lott, I must submit that I could also put everything into a list and then use a variant of quickselect to find the top 1%. Its also not clear to me that the solution is workable because the OP may simply have too much data. I'm just not willing to agree that the heap is the only data structure which is workable.

Comment: "not willing to agree".  Doesn't mean anything.  Rather than fail to agree, you really must propose an  alternative.

Comment: @S.Lott, I have proposed an alternative: modified quickselect. A heap-based algorithm is not the only workable solution to this problem. (It is, I think, the best one). But my point is that you are making an absolute statement: no algorithm besides a heap-based one is workable. To be able to make that claim, you need to demonstrate good reason to believe that no other workable algorithm exists. (Also workable is a little bit vauge)

Comment: Algorithms must be finite, definite and effective.  Effective usually means minimal.  Any O(n log n) algorithm would be effective.  If the quickselect is as fast as the heap insertion, then it seems like it's isomorphic to it.  Perhaps I'm missing something in the quickselect, but the way that it builds partitions sure sounds a lot like way a heap is built.

Comment: @S. Lott, I would take effective to mean that is runs in a reasonable amount of time for the problem under consideration. i.e a program which takes several years is not effective. However, a program which takes two minutes rather the one is still effective, but not as efficient as the other one. But that would be a matter of definition.

Comment: O(n log n) isn't minimal for this problem. O(n log n) is enough time to sort and slice the data which is another technique. Quickselect will solve the problem in O(n). A heap could also solve it in O(n) although the niave heap-based solution will use O(n log n).

Comment: I'm not seeing enough similarity between heap-building and partitioning that they look isomorphic to me. Perhaps I'm missing something. But more to the point, does it matter? From the programmer's perspective the implementation looks fairly different and so you still have choose between one and the other?

Comment: "A heap could also solve it in O(n)".  Correct.  I was wrong because this  is partitioning not a full sort.  "But more to the point, does it matter?"  I have no idea.  I suggested that a heap was the only solution because they appear isomorphic to me.  However, you have split (and resplit) that hair now many, many times.  You tell me.  "does it matter?"  Evidence indicates that it does matter, since you appear to be convinced that it requires extensive discussion.

Comment: @S. Lott, re:  does it matter. That was specifically about your claim of isomorphism between quickselect and heap. Since the end programmer has to choose between heaps and quickselect, claiming that they are isomorphic doesn't help the programmer. He still has to make the choice.

Comment: But let's put this in a practical context: what is the implication of claiming that "heap is the only solution"? As I read it, the implication is that no other algorithm should ever be implemented to solve this problem. But I don't think that statement is correct.

Comment: I also mystified by your claim that I'm splitting hairs. I have no idea what hair you think I'm splitting.

Comment: But let's put this in a practical context: "heap is the only solution".  The way I wrote it, all solutions that are O(n) are isomorphic to a heap, which is minimal.  You **already** suggested this, and I liked your suggestion and wanted to emphasize that your suggestion was very very good.  For some reason, you don't seem to like the idea that your suggestion was very, very good.  What's the point of downgrading your own suggestion by splitting a hair on the *exact* meaning of "only"?

Comment: @S. Lott, I see where you are coming from now. The problem is that your definition of "only" is very different from mine. As a result, your original claim came across as bizarre. There isn't really any point in discussing the meaning of the word, so I'll leave it at that. I wasn't trying to split hairs, but I thought you were trying to claim something that you aren't.

Answer (score 2):

This can't work unless you stipulate a specific size for the partition and do not grow it.

You can't discard any value from the input sequence or you won't get the actual maximum.  The fact that you're popping a value means that you may be discarding a proper part of the solution subset.

Consider a slightly contrived example where X = 0.25. The initial state is to process 1/X items (4 in this case) of which 1 is maximum and 3 are discarded.  The values were 100, 99, 98 and 97.  You keep 100 as the 25% maximum and discard 99, 98, 97.

(You could try to keep all 4 or even the first 25 values.  It doesn't matter how many you keep initially, the logic problem will still arise as soon as you pop a value.  I think the contrived example makes the logic flaw easier to see.)

At some point, you've seen 7 values.  The maxima subset has 1 value (100); the remaining values (99, 98, 96, 95, 94 and 93) have been discarded as not part of the maxima set.

You get value 8, it's 92.  You need to append this to the top set.  Yet, sadly, you discarded a value larger than this.

When you get to value 12, you again need to expand the maxima subset.  However, you will have discarded values that may be larger than the 12th value in the sequence.

You cannot do a `pop()` from the maxima subset unless you can prove the value being popped must be less than all future values which may arrive.